# Trigger event when ethernet adapter state changes Python

Tags: python, events, connection, adapter, ethernet

Trying to create a program that runs 24x7 in the background and undertakes actions triggered by change in the up/down i.e connected/disconnected state of the ethernet adapter port in PCs/Laptops. How to implement the same in Python?

For ex:

```
conn = True
def conCheck()
    if conn == False:
        <trigger onward events>
    else:
        <else statements>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Trying to take up and learn python.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that can request a web page for checking the internet connection.

If there is no internet, You might be getting a ConnectionError.
Otherwise, You'll get a response from the URL. i.e. You're connected with the internet.

Use the following code & try to interrupt the connection your code is executing. You'll see the difference when your internet gets interrupted.

```
import time

import requests

url = "http://www.kite.com"
timeout = 5
conn = True


def conCheck():
    try:
        request = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        print("Connected to the Internet")
        return True
    except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
        print("You're not connected to the internet. ")
        return False


while True:
    conCheck()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hi Vikas, thanks for the prompt reply. My aim is to detect external device connections (say a rouge employee connecting his laptop to one of my systems in my air-gapped network) and take future actions like capping screen, making logs, shutting down services etc(based on if am able to reach my gateway or not every time my eth port is up). This will not work out in that scenario. I intend to fetch his MAC from my ARP to identify the machine and do some other stuff without them knowing. So, need to read the port physical up/down status to branch accordingly.